# How to create a global template where binding properties can be set from outside

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate, controltemplate

I have the following markup in my `UserControl.xaml` file:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=ControlForProjectSettings, Path=ViewModel}" 
    ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Style="{StaticResource HeadingTextBlocksStyle}" 
               Text="Project settings"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource StandardTextBlocksStyle}" 
               Text="Project Number"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource DefaultTextBoxesStyle}"
             Text="{Binding ProjectNumber, 
            Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource StandardTextBlocksStyle}"
               Text="Customer Name"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource DefaultTextBoxesStyle}"
             Text="{Binding CustomerName,
            Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</Grid>
```

and I use a similar method in other user controls, where I want to display a TextBlock and a TextBox next  to each other.

Now I would like the get rid from the duplicated code and use a Template for code blocks like this:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource StandardTextBlocksStyle}" 
           Text="Project Number"/>
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource DefaultTextBoxesStyle}"
         Text="{Binding ProjectNumber, 
        Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Therefore my idea was to create a `ControlTemplate` which look like this:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="OneSettingsEntry">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource StandardTextBlocksStyle}" Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" />
        <TextBox Style="{StaticResource DefaultTextBoxesStyle}"
                 Text="{TemplateBinding TextBoxContent}" />
    </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

and that template I would like to use in `UserControl.xaml` but also in other `User Controls`:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=ControlForProjectSettings, Path=ViewModel}">
    <StackPanel>
        <ListView>
            <ListViewItem Template="{StaticResource OneSettingsEntry }"/>
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

But how can I set the `Text` or `TextBoxContent` property for the `ListViewitem`?

I already found other articles related to this problem, but didn't manage to fix it.

When you have an other suggestion than using a `ControlTemplate`, which would also solve my issue, then bring it on.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not limited by `ControlTemplate` I would use `DataTemplate`.

In `Resources` define [DataTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

```
<Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="YourViewModelTemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:YourViewModel}">
            <Grid 
    ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Style="{StaticResource HeadingTextBlocksStyle}" 
               Text="Project settings"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource StandardTextBlocksStyle}" 
               Text="Project Number"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource DefaultTextBoxesStyle}"
             Text="{Binding ProjectNumber, 
            Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource StandardTextBlocksStyle}"
               Text="Customer Name"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource DefaultTextBoxesStyle}"
             Text="{Binding CustomerName,
            Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
```

And use `DataTemplate` for your `ListView`.

```
<ListView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource YourViewModelTemplate}">
</ListView>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I can also use a `DataTemplate`. But I would like to use the Data Template in the `App.xaml` and make the Binding propertys e.g. `ProjectNumber` kind of variable so I can set them, when I use the Template. Thats because I have other `User Controls`, where I want to use that Template too, but with different Binding properties.